I Can't Connect To Digital Ocean Managed (Postgres) Database
I was working at a WeWork location and have been connected to my DO database the entire week without any issues. Today I left the office for a few hours, came back and found that I was no longer able to connect to my db. I keep getting a Connection Timed Out error.
The DO docs are saying it's due to a firewall issue and I need to add my ip address to the Trusted sources list, but my ip address hasn't changed. Every site I check returns the same ip address I've been using.

After scouring the internet I came across this reddit post that recommended using ipchicken.com to get my current IP address and it worked.
What I don't understand is

How/ why my ip address changed in a few hours and
Why sites such as www.whatismyip.com, nordvpn.com/what-is-my-ip/nordvpn-site/ and even digital ocean are still saying that I'm on the original ip address I started with/ have been using all week?

